# MSSQL create group with multiple condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Scenario: I'm collecting a customer survey. Data collected at a TimePoint(Baseline, 24 Hours, 48 Hours, and 3-5 Days... etc). Table1 contains ID, demographic... etc. Table 2 contains ID, Collect Timepoints. When I do a left join, the output table has multiple Timepoint for one ID.
Here is an example of the table :

```
ID |  HasCollected   |TimeCollect
---|-----------------|----------------
1  |  YES            |Baseline
1  |  NO             |24 Hours
1  |  NO             |48 Hours
2  |  YES            |Baseline
2  |  YES            |24 Hours
2  |  NO             |48 Hours
3  |  NO             |Baseline
3  |  YES            |24 Hours
3  |  NO             |48 Hours
4  |  NO             |Baseline
4  |  YES            |24 Hours
4  |  YES            |48 Hours
```

How do I know how many ID ONLY has `Baseline` collected? or ONLY has `Baseline` and `24 Hours` collected.

```
    For example, ID = 1 collect only Baseline, so he will be in the Baseline group.
                 ID = 2 collected Baseline and 24 Hours. He will be in the BaselineAnd24Hours group but Baseline group.
                 ID = 3 collected 24 Hours, he is in 24Hours group ONLY.
                 ID = 4 collected 24 and 48 hours. He is in 24-48Hours group ONLY. (he is not in group 24 or 48 hours.)
```

I've tried with IIF :

```
  IIF(HasCollected= 'YES' and TimeCollect= 'Baseline' and TimeCollect = '24 Hours', 'G-Base24','NoGroup') as G-BaseAnd24,
  IIF(HasCollected= 'YES' and TimeCollect= 'Baseline', 'G-Base24','NoGroup') as G-Baseline,
```

or with Case

```
 case
        when (HasCollected = 'YES' and CollectTime = 'Baseline') then 'G-Baseline'
        when (HasCollected  = 'YES' and CollectTime  = '24 Hours') then 'G-24Hours'
        when (HasCollected  = 'YES' and CollectTime  = '48 Hours') then 'G-48Hours'
        when ((HasCollected = 'YES' and CollectTime  = 'Baseline') and (HasCollected  = 'YES' and CollectTime  = '24 Hours')) then 'G-BaselineAnd24Hours'
        when ((HasCollected  = 'YES' and CollectTime  = '24 Hours') and (HasCollected  = 'YES' and CollectTime  = '48 Hours')) then 'G-24And48Hours'        
        else 'NoFilter'
        end as filterGroup
```

Outputs are similar in both cases. It can realize ID which has ONLY one timepoint, but if the ID has two or more timepoint, it will still using the first timepoint caught, and not counting them in double timepoint group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT,HasCollected NVARCHAR(10),TimeCollect NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT @Table
VALUES
(1,'YES','Baseline'),
(1,'NO', '24 Hours'),
(1,'NO', '48 Hours'),
(2,'YES','Baseline'),
(2,'YES','24 Hours'),
(2,'NO', '48 Hours'),
(3,'NO', 'Baseline'),
(3,'YES','24 Hours'),
(3,'NO', '48 Hours'),
(4,'NO', 'Baseline'),
(4,'YES','24 Hours'),
(4,'YES','48 Hours')

SELECT TimeCollect, COUNT(*) NumIds
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ID,
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + t.TimeCollect
               FROM @Table t
               WHERE t.ID = t2.ID
               AND t.HasCollected = 'YES'
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1,'') AS TimeCollect
    FROM @Table t2
    GROUP BY t2.ID
)a
GROUP BY TimeCollect
```

Results:

```
TimeCollect         NumIds
24 Hours            1
24 Hours,48 Hours   1
Baseline            1
Baseline,24 Hours   1
```

Or if you have SQL Server 2017+:

```
SELECT TimeCollect, COUNT(*) NumIds
FROM(
    SELECT ID,
           STRING_AGG(TimeCollect,', ') AS TimeCollect
    FROM @Table t
    WHERE t.HasCollected = 'YES'
    GROUP BY ID
)a
GROUP BY TimeCollect
```

Comment: Thank @BJones. It's very closed. The count is showing the correct number. Can we display ID associated with TimeCollect instead of NumIds ?

Comment: What result do you expect if you have ID's 1 and 2 on `24 Hours`? 

`24 Hours`    `1,2`

Something like that?

Comment: I got it BJones. Thank. Your answer is super close to me. I just follow it and play with some more code, then the output is what I need. I can't mark your answer as "This answer is useful" because my rep point is <15, but mark it as accepted. Thank you.